# How to save facebook data

Tags: database, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am very new to Facebook applications and have very basic questions.
I use javascript SDK for my application, that loads friends' names and their profile pics.
How can I store this data into a MySQL database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to store data in a databes you need to have the server process the information and put it there, thus a server script is required.

Most commonly people use php, so what you need to look at is how to get the data from facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

and then how to store the date you got from facebook:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp
(you can do a google search there are loads of resources)

Keep the facebook guidelines on storing data in mind (not quite sure what they look like anymore)

Happy coding!

Comment: you will need a php file which will do the insert commands for the mysql database, you can call that php script with javascript, or have it execute via url by a user.

Comment: thanks.I found some examples and will try to work step by step